# Printing multiple pages of plots onto pdf from within a function

Tags: r, function, pdf, ggplot2, functional-programming

I have written a function that creates several plots. I am trying to paste them onto a pdf arranged in two separate pages.
This is basically how I am trying to do this:

```r
x <- function()
… #does some stuff, makes plots p1:p6 
    pdf(paste(paste(x[1,1], x[1,7], x[1,6],".pdf", sep="")))
    ggarrange(p1,p2,p3, nrow=3, common.legend = T, legend = "top")
    ggarrange(p4,p5,p6, nrow=3, common.legend = T, legend = "top")
    dev.off()
```

The function works fine otherwise, but it is not creating a pdf. do I need to format this differently since it is in a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot plots need to be `print`ed to display. At the command line this happens by default when you run a line. Within a function, the result of each line isn't printed by default, so you need to wrap it in `print()` to give:

```
x <- function()
… #does some stuff, makes plots p1:p6 
    pdf(paste(paste(x[1,1], x[1,7], x[1,6],".pdf", sep="")))
    print(ggarrange(p1,p2,p3, nrow=3, common.legend = T, legend = "top"))
    print(ggarrange(p4,p5,p6, nrow=3, common.legend = T, legend = "top"))
    dev.off()
```